# Formula field reference sibling record

Tags: formula, reference

I have parent object "Contact" with two custom child objects , Contact_Additional_ Info ( Master-Detail) and Program_Registeration ( lookup ). I have already formula field in the second child object(Program_Registeration)  and need update it now to reference a picklist field in the first sibling object  Contact_Additional_ Info) , is it possible that  a formula field on an object can reference sibling objects ? For some reason , i can't change the type of that formula field to another type or change my design data model. Could you please advise me if there is any workaround.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible (as written).

Formulas in Salesforce can only traverse up the relationship hierarchy (child -> parent, going up to 5 levels upwards). We cannot traverse down a hierarchy (from parent -> child), which is what you would need to do.

If you need to do this, then I believe you're looking at needing to write an Apex trigger.

The only other workaround would be to create and maintain a relationship field on "Program_Registeration" to "Contact_Additional_ Info". That assumes that there is one and only one "Contact_Additional_ Info" for each "Program_Registeration".